# Weird behavior with Window style & Xaml through resource section

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    static MyWindow()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyWindow)));
    }
}
```

and my MainWindow.xaml looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="Test" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

I didn't include it to keep things brief, but the button_Click method just new's up a MyWindow and does a Show() on it.

Issues:

1. VS2015 designer shows the backround of the MAIN window (which is
   still a Window, NOT a MyWindow) as green, but doesn't change the
   title. The MAIN window does NOT show green at runtime, so I'm not sure why the designer is picking that up.
2. The MyWindow that gets shown by the button handler doesn't
   get its title set and the background is Black / uninitialized.

Is there a way to define a window using a resource dictionary like I'm trying to do? I'm trying to do it this way so a user of my control (which needs a host Window) can customize the host window if they need to.

Comment: try place `<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyWindow}">` in App.xaml. MyWindow won't find it in MainWindow resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code implies that a window has a *default* style:

```
static MyWindow()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyWindow)));
}
```

This default style should be defined in a resource dictionary called "generic.xaml", located in a folder called "Themes" at the root of your project. These names are by convention. So you should move your style to `Themes/Generic.xaml`. You may also want to base your style on the default one:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyWindow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="Test" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**How to create a custom window in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

Comment: @SledgeHammer: Did you try this or what happened?

Comment: Hi... I just finished trying this. When I moved it to the generic.xaml, it only works once you add in the BasedOn part :). Thanks!